# temperture on rate of mitosis in plants

Tags: mitosis, cytokinesis

does an increase in temperature cause an increase/decrease in the rate of mitosis (ie) the rate of cell division increases, more cells are undergoing mitosis at a  higher temperature? mitotic division increase?)

Comment: Welcome to SE Biology. Please finish reading the [Tour] to learn about this site. We try to use standard English on this site as it is for serious students and professionals in Biology. Sentence in English start with a capital letter — please edit your question and title, and while you are about it do a spelling check. It doesn't look good when the key word of your question is spelled incorrectly in your title.

Answer (score 1):

Mitosis does not occur at very low or very high temperatures. Within the ideal temperature range, the rate of mitosis seems to increase linearly with temperature. That is, higher temperature supports a faster rate of mitosis, and a lower temperature results in a slower mitotic rate.

As a side note, I was able to find many sources surprisingly quickly, and it is recommended that you provide your previous research when creating a question on Stack Exchange. Since you are new here, I have decided to assist you by answering, but be warned that plain questions without any prior effort from your side will get no answers and could even be voted to close.

### Sources

[One](https://www.elveflow.com/microfluidic-flow-control-archives/temperature-control-of-mammalian-cell-cycle/#:%7E:text=Pionneer%20work%20by,spindle%20assembly%20checkpoint.):

> They [work by Engelberg in 1965] showed that temperature controls the rate and speed at which a cell divides ... mitosis was very sensitive to temperature, and that cell cuture subjected to temperature between 24-31°C exhibited an accumulation of cells in mitosis ... the speed at which cells exit mitosis is temperature dependent (Rieder and Maiato, 2002). M-phase length is dependent on temperature and is longer at low temperature, likely due to a decrease in enzymatic activity. However, at high (42-44°C) temperatures, spindle assembly is also impaired and cells do not meet the requirements to proceed through spindle assembly checkpoint.

[Two](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0014482759902903#:%7E:text=The%20rate%20of%20cell%20progress%2C%20or%20mitotic%20rate%2C%20throughout%20the%20mitotic%20cycle%20increases%20linearly%20with%20increase%20in%20temperature%20between%20the%20range%203%20%C2%B0C%20to%2025%20%C2%B0C.):

> The rate of cell progress, or mitotic rate, throughout the mitotic cycle increases linearly with increase in temperature between the range 3 °C to 25 °C.

[Three](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00341516#:%7E:text=Observation%20shows%20that%20at%200%C2%B0%20and%20at%2040%C2%B0%20the%20cells%20do%20not%20go%20through%20the%20cycle%20at%20all%20and%20that%20from%2010%C2%B0%20to%2030%C2%B0%20the%20speed%20increases%20in%20almost%20linear%20proportion.):

> Observation shows that at 0° and at 40° the cells do not go through the cycle at all and that from 10° to 30° the speed increases in almost linear proportion.

Comment: Worth noting: This range may be true for many terrestrial plants, aquatic and marine plants have an optimal temperature that's somewhat lower.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. that's a great point. Feel free to edit my answer!